# how to replace "/" in a file name to "_"

Tags: filenames, rename

I am creating a backup tar files of each mount point:

```
/var
/usr/image
/usr/image/temp
```

I am trying to create tarnames like

```
backup_var_date.tar
backup_usr_image_date.tar
backup_usr_image_temp_date.tar
```

Trying something like below but "mv" not working "$i is a variable calling in for loop"

```
/bin/tar -cvpzf backup_`echo`mv "$i" "${i//"/"/_}``_`hostname`.`date +%m.%d.%Y`.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks odd:

```
backup_`echo`mv "$i" "${i//"/"/_}``_`hostname`.`date +%m.%d.%Y`.tar.gz
```

Are you trying to nest `mv` within `echo` here? The `$(...)` syntax for command substitution would make for easier nesting:

```
backup_$(echo $(mv this that))_$(hostname)...
```

But I still don't see any use for `mv` here, let alone the `echo` which would just repeat what `mv` outputs, and it shouldn't output anything if it works.

We can just nix the `mv`, and build the filename with `${var//\//_}`, which would change all instances of `/` in the variable with `_`.

Perhaps something like this, then, for the whole loop:

```
for path in /var /usr/image /usr/image/temp ; do
    x=$(path#/}                      # remove leading / if there is one
    tarfile=backup_${x//\//_}_$(hostname)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz
    tar -cvpzf "$tarfile" "$path"
done
```

Note: I changed the date format from `05-17-2017` to `2017-05-17` because the latter makes sorting easier. Removing the leading `/` is redundant in that it would get turned into a `_` which we wanted anyway, but I find it somewhat more structured this way.

Comment: It worked :) . If I understood correctly,  {path#/ } removed the /, which was in the beginning and the remaining /'s were replaced by "_" with this input ${x//\//_}.

Comment: @abhi, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful with escaping. Use:

```
"${i//\//_}"
```